# Java list : get next or previous element from an identifier

Tags: java, list, pointers

I want to **navigate into a list by identifier**.

1- I manage/create a list.

2- I create function to get next item of a identifier element from my list

Can you help me to fix this code?

Prepare the list

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("1");
myList.add("2");
myList.add("3");
myList.add("4");
myList.add("5");


public String function getNext(String uid) {

    if (myList.indexOf(uid).hasNext()) {
        return myList.indexOf(uid).nextElement();
    }
    return "";
}

public String function getPrevious(String uid) {
    return myList.indexOf(uid).hasPrevious() ? myList.indexOf(uid).previousElement() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use an index to lookup your String which is faster and simpler however to implement the functions as you have them.

```
public String getNext(String uid) {
    int idx = myList.indexOf(uid);
    if (idx < 0 || idx+1 == myList.size()) return "";
    return myList.get(idx + 1);
}

public String getPrevious(String uid) {
    int idx = myList.indexOf(uid);
    if (idx <= 0) return "";
    return myList.get(idx - 1);
}
```

Using a `List.get(i)` is `O(1)` which makes keeping the index the fastest option. `List.indexOf(String)` is `O(n)`.  Using a NavigatbleSet might appear attractive as it is `O(log n)`, however the cost of creating an object is so high that the collection has to be fairly large before you would see a benefit. (In which case you would use the first option)

Comment: with the only caveat that *indexOf* is an *O(n)* operation but, yup, +1.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, Good point.  This is why retaining the index is better because `List.get(int)` is `O(1)` It may make the code simpler as well.

Answer (score 4):

If your elements are not repeated, what you need is a NavigableSet:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html

The methods `higher` and `lower` are what you are looking for.

Comment: NavigableSet extends SortedSet.  This is not what the OP is after: NavigableSet shall give him the next element in sorted order, no in insertion order.  The OP is after what Peter Lawrey gave as an answer: a method giving him the next/previous element in insertion order.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r In the example elements are inserted in lexicographical order without repetitions, so it was a fair assumption that he was miss-using a list when what he really needed was a sorted set... You know, when all you got is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: are you by any mean trying to imply that all the OP knows would be a hammer?  That would be very rude.  It would also be ironic that you --who knows more than just the hammer-- don't know when to use more than the hammer and when not to.  A bogus answer is a bogus answer: don't try to twist this in your favor.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r What I am implying is that the OP is clearly a programming novice, at least in Java (judging by the syntax errors like the "function" keyword), and he'd better take a look to what the Collections API provides. Even more, I've seen too many times seasoned Java programmers abusing the ArrayList, so this is clearly a common pitfall and it is worth to warn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Lists don't have a `nextElement()` method. `indexOf` returns the integer index of the item. You could simply add (or subtract) one to get the next (or previous) item:

```
public String function getNext(String uid) {
   var index = myList.indexOf(uid);
   if (index > -1) {
     try {
       return myList.get(i+1);
     } catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
       // Ignore
     }
   }
   return ""; // consider returning `null`. It's usually a better choice.
}
```

However looking up an object with `indexOf` on `ArrayList` is a very slow process, because it has to check every single entry. There are better ways to this, but that depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.